# Converting Unity's RGBA array to YUV byte array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yuv, rgba

Unity's `Texture.GetPixels32()` gives us a `Color32[]`, which is an RGBA array that can be converted easily into `byte[]`.

How can we convert this `Color32[]` or RGBA `byte[]` into a YUV `byte[]`?

Also, how does the Alpha value affect the YUV conversion? Online, I mostly see people only trying to convert RGB to YUV. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I know why you're doing this? Where do you need to use this byte array?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the little sample from my code:

```
decimal y = rgb.R * .299000 + rgb.G * .587000 + rgb.B * .114000;
decimal u = rgb.R * -.168736 + rgb.G * -.331264 + rgb.B * .500000 + 128;
decimal v = rgb.R * .500000 + rgb.G * -.418688 + rgb.B * -.081312 + 128;
```

I used the yuv in 0....1 intervall